# How to get AWS OpsWorks instance id within an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-opsworks

Following is the way to get OpsWorks instance id of my current instance:

```
ec2_instance_id=$(ec2-metadata -i)

aws opsworks describe-stacks ---> returns all the stacks

iterate over all stack_ids from above:
    aws opsworks describe-instances --stack-id <stack-id>
    
    iterate over all instances from above:
         if ec2_instance_id == instance's ec2 id:
              return instance's opsworks id
```

But instead of this, is there any way to figure our the OpsWorks id from an instance? Is this information stored anywhere in the instance itself?

Every time I log in to an instance, it's summary is printed as follows:

```
 This instance is managed with AWS OpsWorks.

   ######  OpsWorks Summary  ######
   Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
   OpsWorks Instance: XXXXXX
   OpsWorks Instance ID: XXXXXX
   OpsWorks Layers: XXXXXX
   OpsWorks Stack: XXXXXX
   EC2 Region: XXXXXX
   EC2 Availability Zone: XXXXX
   EC2 Instance ID: XXXXXX
   Public IP: XXXXXXX
   Private IP: XXXXXX
   VPC ID: XXXXX
   Subnet ID: XXXXX
```

Is there any file inside the instance where I can find this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Amazon Linux 2, the ID is in `/etc/aws/opsworks/instance-agent.yml`

Thus you could get it:

```
ops_instance_id=$(sudo grep identity /etc/aws/opsworks/instance-agent.yml | cut -d ' ' -f2)

echo $ops_instance_id
```

example output:

```
54e0799e-bf86-426f-b08c-06530ca6b914
```

Maybe there is simpler way. I know only of the above one.